# SSRS Report - output to screen and a file

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm fairly new to SSRS reports and I'm hoping that there's a simple solution to my problem that I haven't spotted yet...

I have a simple SSRS report that receives a couple of user entered parameters at run time. The DB is queried using these parameters and the results are displayed to the screen in a simple table. Is it possible to have the output automatically written to a csv file as well as to the screen?

I realise that there's the option of the user creating the csv themselves by using the 'export' button when the report has been rendered but I'm trying to avoid that.

What I'm hoping to achieve is to have a report where the user types in their parameter values, clicks 'view report' and can then see their results and create a csv of the output at the same time.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not directly within the SSRS interface.  They would have to render the report before using the Export control.  However, you can accomplish this using URL access, telling the report server the render format at render time.  The browser will then prompt them to download the file for use just as if they had clicked on any other download link.  I use this approach to render a form in WORD for our back office.

Comment: Thanks for your help - that sounds like a good workaround